# Simplest way to automate ticket adding in Trac from C/C++

Tags: c++, automation, trac, ticket-system

I developing program and i writing error handler,
i want to do in her automate error ticket adding to trac webapge.

Anyone know simplest way to do this?
Simplest of connecting libcurl to PHP script on server who adding ticket.

Maybe some library to do this?
Or working code snipet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the server you can programatically add tickets using the trac package in python, which is trac's native language.

If you want to do in C/C++ I think you can achive it issuing xml-rpc calls if the server has the xml-rpc plugin installed[0].

[0] http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/XmlRpcPlugin